# Limit of integral that can't be integrated

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

Given the fuctions $f(x)=e^{x^2}$ and $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$

Show that the limit of $F(x)=\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

---

Here is my thought process

I can see that it looks a lot like a Gaussian integral but reading up on Gaussian integrals didn't really help me.

Here is what I've tried so far

I know $e^{t^2}$ is continuous

$F(x)=\int_0^1f(t)dt+\int_1^xf(t)dt=\int_0^1e^{t^2}dt+\int_1^xe^{t^2}dt$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}x\geqslant 1\implies F(x)&=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+\int_1^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\&\geqslant\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+\int_1^xe^t\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^1e^{t^2}\,\mathrm dt+e^x-e.\end{align}

Comment: I have two follow up questions. 

First: I simple cannot see how the second integral equals $e^x-1$. I even tried with a calculator to simplify as much as I could, and I get $e^x-e$. 

Second: I think I get the basic idea. For example: I know that the integral of $e^{t^2}$ is greater or equal to the same integral of $e^t$ and the integral of $e^t=e-1$ so the integral of $e^{t^2}$ must be greater or equal to $e-1$. Can I then apply it to limits?

Comment: @Sirmimer $$\int_0^xe^t\,\mathrm dt=\left[e^t\right]_{t=0}^{t=x}=e^x-e^0=e^x-1.$$And, yes, you can apply this to limits.

Comment: But isnt it t=1? Meaning it gives $e^x-e^1=e^x-e$

Comment: @Sirmimer My bad! I've edited my answer. Is everything clear now?

Comment: I think so: To sum up. You could rewrite it (as you almost completely did) and then take the limit of it. And if this limit approaches infinity we can use the comparison test (or whatever it's called) for limits to conclude that F(x) must also tend towards infinity as x approaches infinity.

Comment: @Sirmimer I did not re-write it. I replaced $e^{t^2}$ by a smaller function whose integral I knew how to compute and whose limit at $+\infty$ was $+\infty$. Then I compared the limit that I wanted to obtain with this one.

Answer (score 2):

If you have learnt multivariable calculus then following might help.

Let $$I=\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2} dx$$
Similarly we can write $$I=\int_0^{\infty} e^{y^2} dy$$

Hence $$I^2=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2+y^2} dx dy$$

Now using polar coordinates this simplifies to $$I^2=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}}\int_0^{\infty} e^{r^2} rdr d\theta$$
$$\Rightarrow I^2=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} d\theta \int_0^{\infty} e^{r^2} rdr$$
Now substitute $r^2=u$
$$\Rightarrow I^2=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {d\theta}{2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{u} du$$
$$\Rightarrow I^2=\frac {\pi}{4}\cdot (\infty -1)$$
$$\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to \infty} F(x)=\infty$$

Comment: That's the proof I read about on the Gaussian integral but I still didn't get it.

Comment: @Sirmimer Which part do you have doubt in? Or else refer to a sort of similar problem.   https://youtu.be/0a7GuC7kZ6o

Comment: I think what throws me off is the definite integral from 0 to x instead of infinity to infinity (in your case from 0 to infinity)

Comment: @Sirmimer The limit will anyway take care of it